# Custom update in mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am trying to figure out how to update with a custom query. Let me explain:

I have a collection named `items`. When someone hits the user, it will remove `10` from power of any item which has the `type: offence` and if the power after getting hit is less than `0`, it will delete the item. I am currently thinking to use this code:

```js
Item.find({type: 'offence'}, (err, items) => {
    items.forEach(item => {
        if ((item.power - 10) <= 0) {
            Item.deleteOne({id : item .id});
        } else {
            Item.findOne({id: item.id}, (err, item) => {
                item.power -= 10;
                item.save();
            })
        }
    })
})
```

But I believe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Hi Arya, from reading the explanation of what you want to achieve, shouldn't your if statement be flipped?

Comment: Oh thanks, let me update it, but how do

Comment: Try using the update with the aggregation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/ this might help.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I have the linked the github answer